# What is the probability of winning a best of 5 series with varying probability in each game?

Tags: probability

Suppose two friends, A and B, play a best of 5 (first to 3 wins) of 5 different games. Due to skill levels of each player depending on the game, each game has a different probability for each player to win. The outcome of each game is independent of the outcomes of the others.

Label games as G1, G2, G3, G4, G5 (not necessarily played in order).
P(A wins G(i))=p(i)

What is the probability that player A wins the series?

(for the sake of my question, p(1)=0.35, p(2)=0.7, p(3)=0.55, p(4)=0.5, and p(5)=0.4)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: I tried to find the probabilities for all the different outcomes. First, I tried finding the probability of A winning 3-0 (G1, G2, G3). I thought this would be 3!*p(1)*p(2)*p(3), and so on for the other outcomes, but these gave me some very unreasonable results. 

I then tried counting A winning as A winning and B losing (essentially squaring every result and then reapplying combinatorics depending on scoreline). This also gave some unreasonable (at least I think?) results in the 3-2 scoreline.

Comment: For $A$ to win the series, he needs to win at least three games. So calculating the probability of $A$ winning three games would give us our desired result.

$\therefore P(\text {A winning series})= S_3$ where $S_3$ denotes the symmetric sum of $P(1),P(2),\ldots,P(5)$ taking three of them at once.

This is assuming that all the 5 matches will take place regardless the result of previous matches.

Comment: The series ends when one player has exactly 3 wins. Also, I just tried the symmetric sum and got a result greater than 1...

Comment: @theparrot97 I'm sorry, although symmetric sum approach can be used, some of the case are repeated multiple times in it due to which the probability exceeds $1$. I'm really sorry for I hadn't considered that.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ wins the match, that will be because they win either after game 3, after game 4, or after game 5.

- The probability that they win after game 3 is $p(1)p(2)p(3)$
- To win after game 4, $A$ must lose exactly one of the first three games, then win game 4. This has probability
  $$
  \Big(p(1)p(2)(1-p(3))+p(1)(1-p(2))p(3)+(1-p(1))p(2)p(3)\Big)p(4)
  $$
- Finally, if $A$ is to win the match only after game five, they must lose two of the first four games, and then win the fifth:
  $$
  \Big(p(1)p(2)(1-p(3))(1-p(4))+p(1)(1-p(2))p(3)(1-p(4))+(1-p(1))p(2)p(3)(1-p(4))+p(1)(1-p(2))(1-p(3))p(4)+(1-p(1))p(2)(1-p(3))p(4)+(1-p(1))(1-p(2))p(3)p(4)\Big)p(5)
  $$

Comment: Thanks for this @arthur. However, the games are not necessarily played in order. Hence, the probability of winning 3-0 of G1G2G3 is p(1)p(2)p(3), which is the same as winning 3-0 of permutations of G1G2G3. However, that is different to winning 3-0 of G2G3G4, and its permutations, and so on.

Comment: I suppose I take your model and symmetric sum it? But the problem is that the sum of all combinations for winning 3-0 gives me a number greater than 1.

Comment: @theparrot97 Regardless of the order, the probability of winning the match is the same. So I just chose an arbitrary order, and went from there. If you want to include order, then there are 120 of them, and each of them has a calculation much like this one, ending up in exactly the same end probability. Then you average them to get the final answer. You're welcome to do that if you want. I prefer not to